# Python 2.6 importing packages (psyco) on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, bash, psyco

Why does importing psyco work when I call my script directly, but when I call it from a bash script it fails???

test.sh:

```
while true
do
    python test.py;
    sleep 10;
done
```

test.py:

```
try:
    import psyco
    print "Got psyco!"
except ImportError:
    print "No psyco."
```

And now...

```
> python test.py
```

"Got psyco!"

```
> ./test.sh
```

"No psyco."

"No psyco."

...

Comment: Well you are in different directories when running it.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 version of Python installed on this system.

Different environment was invoking a different version of python, which did not have psyco.